# xsl:fo different colors/fonts in one block

Tags: xsl-fo

Suppose I have an xsl:fo block:

```
<fo:block>one two three</fo:block>
```

Can I make "three" a different color than "one" and "two"? Note: I'd rather NOT use a table for this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can us an [`<fo:inline>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xsl-20011015/xslspec.html#fo_inline) element.

> The fo:inline formatting object is commonly used for formatting a
>   portion of text with a background or enclosing it in a border.

For example, in order to make the word "three" red:

```
<fo:block>one two <fo:inline color="#FF0000">three</fo:inline></fo:block>
```

Comment: I need something similar like this but not with text; only square boxes with background color only. I gave a background-color, but without content that's not working. How can I do that?

Comment: Create a question and post a minimal example of your xsl-fo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67724887/xsl-fo-empty-inline-block-with-background-color