# XSL-FO : empty inline block with background color

Tags: xsl-fo

I want to create an empty inline block with some color in it, but if the `<fo:inline>` element doesn't have any content then it doesn't work.

For the snippet included below, the one with the background color red doesn't work.

Creating a table and giving a table cell a background color to solve this would be my last option. How can I do it without a table?

```xml
<fo:block>
  <fo:inline background-color="black" padding-left="2pt" padding-right="2pt" margin-right="22pt" color="white">MY_SKU</fo:inline>
  <fo:inline background-color="red" margin-right="22pt" width="7pt" height="7pt"></fo:inline>
  <fo:inline>Red</fo:inline>
</fo:block>
```

I want like this: [image: sku with black bg color description]

Comment: `fo:inline` won't take up space unless something is inside to fill it. Are you trying to make the background of the `fo:block` red except for the black `fo:inline` with MY_SKU?

Comment: Or are you attempting to create some sort of red vertical line showing separation between `MY_SKU` and `Red`?

Comment: Is this what you may want:
put an &#160; char inside the empty inline: 
<fo:inline background-color="red" margin-right="22pt" width="7pt" height="7pt">&#160;</fo:inline>

Comment: use an <fo:leader> inside the inline and set the leader-length

Comment: I have added the image for how I want it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking to achieve?

[image]

```
<fo:block>
  <fo:inline background-color="red" margin-right="22pt" width="7pt" height="7pt">
    <fo:inline background-color="black" padding-left="2pt" padding-right="2pt" margin-right="22pt" color="white">MY_SKU</fo:inline>
  </fo:inline>
  <fo:inline>Red</fo:inline>    
</fo:block>
```

Comment: I have added an image in the question for what I want to achieve.